# Can Blender be used online for viewing and editing my 3D model?

Tags: webgl

I want to use Blender for a sketch-up 3D image, but I want my 3D image online, on my webpage. I also want to be able to edit it online as well... Are there any available option for doing this?

Hope you all have something related to this my problem that can help me out.

Comment: The answer to your question is `no`, since blender its self doesn't run online, but I think it could be re-titled to be less specific: Blender compatible online model viewing solutions.

Comment: then what is the solution for my question??

Comment: there are multiple online model viewers as is given in the answer by sambler.

Comment: no I want editor online? then there is possible chance of doing this?

Comment: Why do you have the 3D printing tag? Do you want a physical print of your 3D model?

Comment: What kind of editing are you looking for?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, what kind of viewing, what level of editing is needed?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're hoping that Blender is run on Java and you're looking for an online Java applet of it?

Comment: Java D, we can't answer unrelated questions (as you have asked in the [comment](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1845/can-blender-be-used-online-for-viewing-and-editing-my-3d-model#comment3204_1846) you posted below. This site is about Blender, and we also expect reasonable questions that we can actually understand and answer (see the [Help page](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help)).

Comment: Hmmm - I just found a new project started 10 days ago that allows sculpting in a web browser - any chance your just trolling for links and advertising?

Answer (score 6):

For displaying a 3d model online checkout [sketchfab](http://sketchfab.com/) or [p3d](http://p3d.in/)

I don't expect much in the way of mesh editing online.

As you tagged your question as 3d-printing [shapewright](http://www.shapewright.com/) may be close to what you want - it is designed for customised 3d printing. The site uses an automated method that can join several pre-built models together to get a final model. I'd expect Dolf to be helpful if you wanted to make use of his scripts.

Comment: @sambler..okay then can you have idea about how to count cells which is in image?

Comment: Counting cells in an image sounds more like optical recognition and has nothing to do with blender. I'm wondering if you are asking about a 3d model or an image that has a 3d effect in it? I think you may be better off asking in a forum where you can give more detail, discuss options and respond to questions for more detail.

Comment: As an addition: SculptGL http://stephaneginier.com/sculptgl/ is a very new webGL application running in your browser that is capable of loading/saving and sculpting a mesh online.. maybe this is of help too for you!