# integration of blender file into webstorm?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I need help for my Final Year Project, I want to know that how can I integrate .blender file into my webpage? i didn't get any answer from anywhere. please I need help. answer it as soon as possible

Comment: You might want to take a look at these two: [How can I use my Blender models in WebGL](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/408/2217) and [Can Blender be used online for viewing and editing my 3D model?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1845/2217)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a hosted solution for presenting 3D models online you may look into services like [p3d.in](http://p3d.in/) or [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/)

If you want an easy (as in GUI workflow) self hosted solution directly from inside Blender check out [Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com/en/)